# Java issue loading image

Tags: java, image, imageicon

for some reason i cannot load certain images with my java program. just above this snippet of code i have another image referral that works fine.

```
for(int x = 1; x<=7; x++){
        if(additionals[x] != 0){
            rightPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("IMAGES/image"+x+".GIF")));
            count++;
        }
    }
```

images are saved in a folder named IMAGES
and are called image1.gif, image2.gif etc if you need the rest of my code just ask

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're looking in the right location for the images? If you run this line: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` what returns? Is your IMAGES directory in the correct location relative to the user directory (the path String output from the line of code I've given above)? For instance, if it returns `C:\Users\Foo\Documents\workspace\bar` then IMAGES should be at: `C:\Users\Foo\Documents\workspace\bar\IMAGES`

Comment: yes i am positive that i am looking in the right folder like i said i have other lines that reference images from the same folder and using the same path just "IMAGES/filename"+aValue+".gif" not a few lines above the code and eblow it that works no problems

Comment: Your pastebin code is different from your code posted above. Which is correct? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: sorry i copied my code while i was testing thought id changed it back the code i posted here is correct. and no i dont get any errors ram images show up fine and empty images show up fine just not image1, image 2 etc

Comment: line 363 works, line 373 works line 368 puts something into the grid but noting visible http://bayimg.com/MAMNPAaDC

Comment: Many won't download files, but I will.  Could you upload the smallest of the files that work/do not work to an image share site, or embed them here?

Answer (score 2):

1. is it windows? `GIF != gif` otherwise
2. does it work if you remove condition `(additionals[x] != 0)`?
3. is `rightPanel` big enough for all images?

Comment: thanks for getting back super quick i cannot understand why this one line doesnt work i think it has something to do with my file naming if i replace "IMAGES/image"+x+".GIF" with another image that is saved in the same folder it works fine. im  using net beans if that has anything to do with it but the directory is correct because i have other lines of code within the same program that reference other images saved in that very folder that works fine

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this:

```
    if (additionals[0] != 0){
        rightPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("IMAGES/ram"+additionals[0]+"gb.gif")));
        count++;
    }
    for(int x = 1; x<=7; x++){
        if (additionals[x] != 0){
            rightPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("IMAGES/image"+x+".gif")));
            count++;
        }
    }
```

shouldn't really be this?

```
    if (additionals[0] != 0){
        rightPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("IMAGES/ram"+additionals[0]+"gb.gif")));
        count++;
    }
    for(int x = 1; x<=7; x++){
        if (additionals[x] != 0){
            rightPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("IMAGES/image"+ additionals[x]+".gif")));
            count++;
        }
    }
```

?

It would make your code appear more symmetric.  Otherwise, do printlns before the offending line with the String that you want to use to make the ImageIcon to be sure that it's correct.

For example:

```
    for(int x = 1; x<=7; x++){
        if (additionals[x] != 0){
            String imagePath = "IMAGES/image"+x+".gif";
            System.out.println("imagePath = " + imagePath);
            rightPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imagePath)));
            count++;
        }
    }
```

And then compare the Strings that are output with the file names and paths. Even better is to create a new File and output its full path before trying to use it to create a new ImageIcon.

caveat: code has not been tested.

Comment: for the first part yes im sure it shouldnt be that if you look at the comments at the beginning of my code the additionals array after the first one, additionals[1..7] is an integar equivalent of a boolean so only ever 0 or 1, the code you posted there would only ever load one image and that would be image1 all the time how ive done it is that additionals[1] equals warranty so if additionals[1] == 1 then load imgae1.gif additionals[5] equals monitor (or whatever) so if additionals[5] == 1 then load image5.gif

Comment: also for the second part i have tried println's and as far as i can tell they are just how they should be. i can uplaod my directory to a file share site so anyone can run it if they please, it may just be my machine, ive not had chance to try it on another yet.

Comment: How about posting a listing of all the files in the IMAGES directory?

Comment: I'm not downloading any files. Post a print out of the directory itself here in the forum. Also verify that your images are not corrupt.

Comment: *"Also verify that your images are not corrupt"*  +1 - also that the images are encoded in a GIF format that Java understands.

Comment: as far as i can tell the images are not corrupt they open with every image viewer / editor i have on the laptop. as for the encoding the ones that are not loading are the same encoding as the ones that are. i beleive the issue is the naming i figured out this morning that if i change the name to a proper word e.g keyboard.gif then reference it it loads no problem, it just means that i will have to come up with another way to write my loop, and the bayimg link is not a download it was a screenshot of my directory